# How to connect a bistable valve?

Tags: relay, control, short-circuit, solenoid-valve

I need to control a [bi-stable valve](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005003214000529.html?spm=a2g0o.order_list.0.0.4ce35e5bhA5axv&gatewayAdapt=glo2fra):

[image]

Here is the typical wiring provided for such 3 wires type valve:

[image]

But I don't want to continue to feed it when actually closed or opened which is normaly unnecessary. I foresee two solutions with pro and cons:

1. Add a relay on the return line. Process is switch the open/close relay first, then close the return line relay the time necessary for the transition with a pulse of the desired length. Here, no risk to feed both open and close inputs the same time.
2. Let the return line always connected like on the picture, and have two relays for control, one to open and one to close. The process would be easier, one pulse on one of the control relay, but with a risk to switch both on the same time and hurt the valve.

Both make use of two relays. What is the best solution?

Comment: Does the valve not automatically switch off when it reaches the end of its travel?  So while voltage may still be present it’s drawing no current.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a link to the datasheet for the valve.

Comment: @Frog it is not in the datasheet which is very succinct. But if it is the way all bi-syable valve works, then it solves my issue

Comment: @Transistor : done

Comment: Unfortunately that's not a datasheet link - it's a link to a shop site. There are reasons that those sites are cheap and lack of technical documentation is one of them. "*No datasheet? No sale!*"

Comment: @Transistor, you are right, but sometimes, not cheap = no project at all

Comment: @Frog, I have the answer from the manufacturer, first he answered no, but when I asked how much is the consumption after it has reached the end of its travel, he has answered: "This does not consume electricity, but only consumes electricity during the process of opening and closing". So you can put your remark as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP has confirmed that the valve automatically switches off power when it reaches the end of its travel, so while voltage may still be present it’s drawing no current and so there’s no need for an additional external switch.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the used bistable valve usually the internal control circuit has already an interlock and a limit switch. But if not the first solution is better however you can simply avoid adding a delay "switch the open/close relay first, then close the return..." by using the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgPyBg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here's how.

[image]

An SPDT toggle switch is all that is required. At the end of opening / closing, the corresponding limit switch de-energises the motor.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is really simple: Feed the NO contact of each relay from the NC contact on the other relay.

This way both relais interlock each other, and there will be open circuit if both are active at the same time.

Comment: I have tried to figure it out with no success. Could you post a schema please?